# How to add image connecting 2 cells?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I have list of people that I want to present in table list. I have already made the table and cells. What I now what is - if two people are married, i want to to show their cells, one above the other, and image of rings (wedding rings), that connects these cells, it will be partly over both cells,

Is there to do this the elegant way, or do i have to make special cell that is twice the size of normal cell, and contains records of two people?

Comment: and if you split the image of the ring? in the first cell, you will see the top half of the image of the ring, and in the second cell you will see the lower half of the image of the ring... is just an idea, but it might work

Comment: I suppose you could try to get the rects for the cells in question via `rectForRowAtIndexPath:` and add the rings image as a subview of your tableview (though you loose in performance since they are not reusable)

Comment: You should go with special cell that is twice the size of normal cell and contains records of two people.